# Creating Database in MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, mysql-workbench

I'm new in MySQL Workbench. I'm planning to create a new database called "Customers". But the problem is I don't know how to create it. I already installed it and I can see the "New Connection" at the left bottom of the GUI. Should I click it? Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: RTFM? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-sql-development.html

Comment: See this question: [create a new database with MySQL Workbench](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5515745/145173)

Answer (score 1):

You probably got a local instance of MySQL running (which should be listed in your window above 'new connection').

Connect to it (or create a new connection and connect)

Use the button toolbar and select 'Create new schema'. The button with the database icon and a add sign (+).

That's it..

Or read the manual as stated in the first comment ;)