# Is there anyway to create sql statements from a database diagram in MySql workbench

Tags: mysql, sql, database, relational-database, mysql-workbench

I am completely new to databases so please don't be too harsh but is there anyway to create a database by using an EER diagram and have that convert to SQL statements?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create a new MySQL database using Workbench](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9087482/create-a-new-mysql-database-using-workbench)

Answer (score 0):

There's a question from last year that covers this: [Create a new MySQL database using Workbench](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9087482/create-a-new-mysql-database-using-workbench)

Apparently, you gotta go to Database -> Forward Engineer.