# How to create a new Database in MySQL Workbench 6.0?

Tags: mysql, database, database-connection, mysql-workbench

I found [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5515745/create-a-new-database-with-mysql-workbench), but still can't create a new Database.

I was also told that the default the password for root is blank, that didn't work, tried password, root etc :(

I'm stuck at the password screen.

The only thing I can gather is that the default ip I was given doesnt work.

1. Check that mysql is running on server 127.0.0.1
2. Check that mysql is
   running on port 3306 (note: 3306 is the default, but this can be
   changed)

According to [this tutorial on their site](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-getting-started-tutorial-admin.html), I need to check that mysql is running on the right server ip, but how do I even do that? :(

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the first problem here is the login. If blank as password is not working for you. Try to set a password first and then proceed with next steps

Here are instructions to reset/set the password for first time

```
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/resetting-permissions.html
```

Or use

```
mysqladmin -u root password NEWPASSWORD
```

Once you are logged in you can easily create a database.

Comment: Thanks, that is the right answer.. my setup was strange though and uncommon