# Create database from script in mysql Workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Is it possible to create database from sql script file MySQl Workbench ?

There is an option to add sql script but where do we execute the query ?

The execute query button is not visible.

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5515745/create-a-new-database-with-mysql-workbench

Answer (score 0):

This question very likely refers to the modeling section of MySQL Workbench. The ability to add an SQL script is part of a model.

[image]

However, this section is not for general SQL work. For directly working on a server, loading scripts and running them, creating real tables and all that, open a connection from the homescreen. You will get an SQL IDE that allows to either run sql commands manually or to open object editors for common db objects like tables, stored routines, views etc. via the context menu in the schema sidebar:

[image]