# Trying to create a NEW database in MySQL workbench 6.3 (Icons are grayed out - why)

Tags: mysql, centos, mysql-workbench, mariadb, mariasql

In reference to the Stack Overflow post found at the line below, The icons referred to in the post are grayed out in my case.

[Create a new database with MySQL Workbench](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5515745/create-a-new-database-with-mysql-workbench)

My system

- CentOS 7
- MariaDB (all documentation I have read on MySQL workbench states that it will work with MariaDB)
- MySQL workbench 6.3.7 build 1199 CE (64 bits) community

[MySQL workbench version snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m2swj.png)

My Icons are grayed out.

[Grayed out Icons in MySQL workbench](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xiu96.png)

Comment: Well, probably the account you are using does not have the internal permissions to perform these actions...

Comment: Your MySQL/MariaDB server is not running.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my own problem. Here to share the answer should somebody else make this mistake.

Go here and read this.

https://www.certdepot.net/rhel7-install-mariadbmysql/

**The problem**

I had installed mariadb, but did not run the command **"mysql_secure_installation"** from the CentOS 7 command line (terminal).

Therefore the service was not starting. Also I had failed to examine the totality of the MySQL workbench screen and notice that there was no connection to the server.

[MySQL Workbench No Connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MrYAM.png)

Answer (score 0):

When your server is up and running, and MySQL workbench has connected to it your screen should look like this.

By the way, I am understanding that in this utility a **"schema"** and a **"database"** are the same thing. But I am still new at this, so a more experienced user should comment on this post to verify if that is true or not for the benefit of other new SQL users.

[MySQL Workbench properly connected - and ready to create new schemas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5YVyg.png)