# Create a database with mysql workbench

Tags: mysql, sql, database, web, mysql-workbench

I am a beginner in the web and I would like to create a database with a user "username : admin / password : admin". 
The fact is that I really don't know much about databases.

I have installed MySQL Workbench on my computer but I don't know if it is enough on its own or if I also need to install MySQL...

Can we create a complete database only with MySQL Workbench or MySQL Workbench is only a complement to MySQL and cannot work without?

I started to take inspiration from that: [Create a new database with MySQL Workbench](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5515745/create-a-new-database-with-mysql-workbench)

But the subject is 8 years old and I didn't want to dig it up to ask my questions.

Comment: No you need also ti install mysql. Then connect workbench and then add a new schema and then a new datable

Comment: just google 'ho to install mysql on '+ you operating system, follow a guide (better if from website like digital ocean), an at the end probably they will teach you how to create a user on mysql, and than you just need to tell the credentials to mysql workbench, and you are done

Answer (score 1):

Yes - You have to install MySQL server. Workbench is a tool for sending queries to MySQL server